# Repeat Gapless WAVE playback on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, linux, media-player

I have a .wav file (a drum beat) that I want to use to play along with. The problem I am encountering is that I can't get either VLC or Windows Media Player (both on Windows 7) to play the file in repeat mode gaplessly, which makes it useless since it's a drum beat and it needs to be precise.

Is there some program on either Windows 7 or linux that you know can do this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Got it working in Audacity on Linux, but it's a little heavy, is there anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody replied, so for googlers I guess Audacity is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

I ran across this post looking for a fix for this problem. I'm trying to loop some soothing sounds as background noise (running water, crickets, etc.), but the gap shows up when the track repeats, even when the crossfade in WMP11 is turned on and is set to 0 seconds as has been suggested in other forums.

Unfortunately, gapless playback doesn't seem to work in WMP when you only have a single track set to repeat.

After some tinkering, I found a working solution to this problem. It should work for most file types, but it's working for me with .wav and .mp3 files. Here are the steps:

1. Add your *sound.wav* file to the WMP playlist
2. Add the same *sound.wav* file to your WMP playlist again so that you have two instances of the same track in the playlist
3. Make sure your WMP crossfade settings are set to ON and 0.0 Seconds ([howto](http://www.windows-media-player-updates.com/windowsmediaplayercrossfade.html))
4. Select the Repeat toggle button so the playlist repeats and click Play

There is no gap as WMP moves between playlist entries, and of course, they're both the same track, so you effectively have gapless repeating playback of a single track.

-eg